# Getting posts associated to specific user with Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a piece of code that pulls all of the posts from my Firebase database. I'm trying to make the code pull all posts for a specific user id. The structure of my database is that user ids have a set of post ids associated to them.

[image]

[image]

The code that I have to pull all of the posts:

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    self.posts = []
    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshot {
            print("SNAP: \(snap)")
            if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let key = snap.key
                let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                self.posts.append(post)
            }
        }
    }
    self.feedTableView.reloadData()
})
```

How I identify my current user:

```
_ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth,user) in
            if let user = user {
                let userId = user.uid
                print("USER: \(String(describing: userId))")
                let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(userId)").child("posts")
                //print("NEW POST: \(newPost.child)")
                newPost.setValue([userPost : true])

            }
        }
```

It looks like I need to get to the child (posts) of the users object and then cycle through the posts. How can I loop through (and observe for changes) the posts associated to the user that is signed in?

EDIT (Trying to cycle through all of a user's posts):

```
_ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth,user) in
    if let user = user {
        let userId = user.uid
        print("USER: \(String(describing: userId))")
        let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(userId)").child("posts")
        newPost.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.posts = []
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    print("ERIC SNAP: \(String(describing: snap.value))")
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.feedTableView.reloadData()
        })
        //print("NEW POST: \(newPost)")

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to attach a listener to each post for which you have a key under that user's node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added an edit above. Is this what you are recommending? Something still seems off because the value I get when I print `ERIC SNAP` is `ERIC SNAP: Optional(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the signed in user's posts is done as follows:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        print("USER ID: \(uid)")
        let newPost = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid)").child("posts")

        newPost.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.posts = []
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    let postData = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(snap.key)
                    postData.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            let key = snapshot.key
                            let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                            self.posts.append(post)
                        }
                        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }

        })
```